# Reduce the width of a UWP NumberBox

Tags: uwp

I'm trying to reduce the width of a UWP [Numberbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/number-box). If you just set the `Width` property, the right hand side of the numberbox gets truncated like:

[image]

I've tried setting the `MinWidth` property, and (based on what I could find in the default template) also reduced the `NumberBoxMinWidth` theme resource but nothing changes.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try select your Numberbox, then right click in desginer view then

[image]

Edit template => Edit copy

Should give you a copy of control template, where you can setup internals...

The width of text box comes not only from Width property, but also from Margins and Padding, it's maybe enough to set thouse, otherwise you have to make a Template copy and check witch component is not letting for it to become smaller...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've upvoted because you're correct that the answer is somewhere in the template, however as I said in my question I'd already looked in the default template but couldn't find what was maintaining the width.

Comment: @Siyh, had a quick look today, seems quite a bit of code but I think it’s a button or text box that don’t let it go down, gonna look tommo or after tomorrow

Comment: It's by design, please go to [source](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/2337f7b828eddb33b75a97154f3ca9575d732657/dev/NumberBox/NumberBox_themeresources.xaml#L61) code, the default  `NumberBoxMinWidth` 120, if you want set value small than 120 , it will not work.

Comment: So you need edit  style and edit InputBox minwidth [manually](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/60cfdb643002bcc1b751c2a3d1ec825aac2d0b09/dev/NumberBox/NumberBox.xaml#L145)